# Continuous transformation and corresponding infinitesimal transformation

Tags: calculus, transformation

I have a continuous transformation given by
$$\vec r_i(t)\to\tilde{\vec r_i}(t)=\frac{1}{s}\vec r_i(s^2t), \ \ \ i=1,2$$
Taking $s=1+\epsilon$ we aim to find the corresponding infinitesimal transformation given by
$$\vec r_i(t)\to\tilde{\vec r_i}(t)=\vec r_i(t)+\epsilon\zeta_i(r_i,\dot{\vec r_i},t), \ \ \ i=1,2$$
**Solution**

Beginning with
$$\frac{1}{1+\epsilon}\vec r_i((1+\epsilon)^2t)$$
and approximating, utilising the fact that $\epsilon^2\approx0$ we have
$$(1-\epsilon)\vec r_i(t+2\epsilon t)=(1-\epsilon)(\vec r_i(t)+\vec r_i(2\epsilon t))+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$$
Which gives
$$(1-\epsilon)(\vec r_i(t)+2\epsilon t\dot{\vec r_i}(t))+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$$
Utilising $\epsilon^2\approx0$ once more we obtain
$$\vec r_i(t)+\epsilon(2 t\dot{\vec r_i}(t)-\vec r_i(t))+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$$
finally we have
$$\zeta_i=2 t\dot{\vec r_i}(t)-\vec r_i(t)$$
I am unsure of the validity of $\vec r_i(2\epsilon t)=2\epsilon t\dot{\vec r_i}(t)$, would anyone be able to advise me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The infinitesimal transformation just means we're considering $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}^2$ defined as
\begin{align}
f(\epsilon)&=\frac{1}{1+\epsilon}\mathbf{r}((1+\epsilon)^2t),
\end{align}
and we want to calculate the derivative $f'(0)$ at the origin; i.e this is what you're calling $\zeta$. From the product/chain/quotient rules, we have
\begin{align}
f'(\epsilon)&=\left(-\frac{1}{(1+\epsilon)^2}\right)\mathbf{r}((1+\epsilon)^2t)+
\frac{1}{1+\epsilon}\dot{\mathbf{r}}((1+\epsilon)^2t)\cdot (2(1+\epsilon)t)
\end{align}
Hence, evaluating at $\epsilon=0$ yields
\begin{align}
f'(0)&=-\mathbf{r}(t)+2t\,\dot{\mathbf{r}}(t)
\end{align}
In other words, $\zeta(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{v},t)=-\mathbf{r}+2t\mathbf{v}$ is the "infinitesimal transformation".

Also, just to emphasize: we're keeping $t$ (which we like to imagine as the "curve parameter") fixed. We're letting $\epsilon$ (the so called "variation-parameter") vary. Differentiating with respect to $\epsilon$ at $0$ thus describes how (to first order) things are changing when the modify the curve itself. Hence, it is called the infinitesimal (which means first order) transformation.

---

Note that if you want to arrive at this via a "Taylor expansion", then you're essentially going to be reproving the basic rules of differential calculus. Strictly speaking, we can only use the big-oh $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$ if we assume the functions are $C^1$ (which is actually an unnecessary assumption); first derivatives deal with little-oh $o(\epsilon)$. Anyway, if you don't care about such technicalities, and would like to see how to arrive at the infinitesimal transformation the "physics way", here it is:
\begin{align}
f(\epsilon)&=\frac{1}{1+\epsilon}\mathbf{r}((1+\epsilon)^2t)\\
&=(1-\epsilon + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2))\cdot \mathbf{r}\left(t+ 2\epsilon t+ \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)\right)\tag{i}\\
&=(1-\epsilon + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2))\cdot \left[\mathbf{r}(t)+ \left(2\epsilon t+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)\right)\,\dot{\mathbf{r}}(t) + \mathcal{O}\left(\left(2\epsilon t+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)\right)^2\right)\right]\tag{ii}\\
&=(1-\epsilon + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2))\cdot \left[\mathbf{r}(t)+2\epsilon t\, \dot{\mathbf{r}}(t) + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)\right]\\
&=\mathbf{r}(t)+ \epsilon\left[-\mathbf{r}(t)+2t\dot{\mathbf{r}}(t)\right]+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)
\end{align}
hence the thing in square brackets is once again what we found above for $f'(0)$. Note that in going from (i) to (ii), what I did was to define the quantity $\eta=2\epsilon t+ \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$, so that
\begin{align}
\mathbf{r}(t+2\epsilon t + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2))=\mathbf{r}(t+\eta)=\mathbf{r}(t)+\eta \,\dot{\mathbf{r}}(t)+\mathcal{O}(\eta^2).
\end{align}
Then, I plugged in the definition of $\eta$, simplified the resulting algebra, and used some basic properties of big-oh, such as a function being $\mathcal{O}(\eta^2)$ implying that it is also $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$ and so on.

---

You mention

> I am unsure of the validity of $\vec r_i(2\epsilon t)=2\epsilon t\dot{\vec r_i}(t)$...

Well, you're right to be suspicious because this is completely false. You can't bring scalars out of a function and replace it with a derivative. Remember that the if a function $g$ is differentiable at a point $a$, then $g(a+\epsilon)=g(a)+\epsilon \cdot g'(a)+o(\epsilon)$ (or if you assume $C^1$ then you can put $\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$ for the remainder). But I hope the above explanation is sufficient to understand where the $2\epsilon t$ is actually coming from.

Comment: I have a number of questions. Could you explain why $\mathcal{C}^1$ is an unnecessary assumption. What does it entail do say this? Why is $\zeta=f’(0)$? With regards to the technicalities involving the little-oh, could you suggest a resource where I could learn about the properties and use cases of oh notation? Many thanks for the extremely detailed answer!

Comment: @benmcgloin look at what you've written in your post. The way you introduced $\zeta_i$ is "the thing being multiplied by $\epsilon$". This is literally the definition of taking the derivative with respect to $\epsilon$ at $0$. That's why $\zeta=f'(0)$. Also, since we're only taking the derivative at $\epsilon=0$, we only need once differentiability of $\mathbf{r}$. Regarding little and big oh, I'm sure wikipedia has a good enough explanation. Also, Loomis and Sternberg's Advanced Calculus section 3.5 is about the big and little oh notation.